が/を alignment for わかる and exhaustive listing
I came across an interesting sentence just yet:

聞いてたよな？今日のバイトのあと、トーマと一緒に待ち合わせ場所に来て。


場所はあいつがわかってる。何もないとは思うけど、一応気をつけろよ。
[emphasis mine]

“あいつ” in this case refers to “トーマ” who is a friend of both speaker and listener.
Common folkore holds that “わかる” may only select a nominative/accusative rather than dative/nominative alignment where it expresses a volitional form of understanding typically used to understand someone's position or emotions or sympathize with them but that evidently does not seem to be the case here at and the “〜が” seems to be used with the exhaustive listing function here so what's going on here? Is it because the “〜ている” form is used or does the exhaustive listing function with the object as the topic allow “〜わかる” to select nominative/accusative alignment regardless of this and how much of this transfers over to other predicates that also carry dative/nominative alignment such as say “必要”?

It seems influenced by 知っている, though it is just my speculation.

Can you explain nominative/accusative alignment and dative/nominative alignment?

@YusukeMatsubara with the former I mean the subject marked with “〜が” and the object with “〜を”. With the latter the subject marked with “〜に” and the object with “〜が”. Traditionally, わかる is of the latter, as in “私にこれがわかる。” but say “私があなたの気持ちをわかってあげるよ。” also occurs with the former, more standard alignment for Japanese verbs.

@YusukeMatsubara, Zorf, there is no nominative object. That is an artifact of trying to interpret Japanese grammar into English. 分かる is better thought of as "to be understandable". In this rendering, が is easily understood as the normal subject marker, and に as the agent marker. [誰々【だれだれ】] に [何々【なになに】] が 分かる → "[something] is understandable by [someone]".

@YusukeMatsubara, Zorf, other readers — 分かる【わかる】 is derivationally the passive conjugation of verb 分く【わく】 ("to distinguish; to split something up"). I believe this is why this behaves grammatically like a passive or potential verb — because it is one.
